# Wireless driver not detected

Tags: 11.04, networking, wireless

When typing iwconfig I only get "no wireless extensions"

How do I get the Ubuntu wireless driver to be detected?

`lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: ATI Technologies Inc RS690 Host Bridge
00:01.0 PCI bridge: ATI Technologies Inc RS690 PCI to PCI Bridge (Internal gfx)
00:04.0 PCI bridge: ATI Technologies Inc Device 7914
00:05.0 PCI bridge: ATI Technologies Inc RS690 PCI to PCI Bridge (PCI Express Port 1)
00:06.0 PCI bridge: ATI Technologies Inc RS690 PCI to PCI Bridge (PCI Express Port 2)
00:12.0 SATA controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB600 Non-Raid-5 SATA
00:13.0 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB600 USB (OHCI0)
00:13.1 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB600 USB (OHCI1)
00:13.2 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB600 USB (OHCI2)
00:13.3 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB600 USB (OHCI3)
00:13.4 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB600 USB (OHCI4)
00:13.5 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB600 USB Controller (EHCI)
00:14.0 SMBus: ATI Technologies Inc SBx00 SMBus Controller (rev 14)
00:14.1 IDE interface: ATI Technologies Inc SB600 IDE
00:14.2 Audio device: ATI Technologies Inc SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: ATI Technologies Inc SB600 PCI to LPC Bridge
00:14.4 PCI bridge: ATI Technologies Inc SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] HyperTransport Technology Configuration
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Address Map
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] DRAM Controller
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Miscellaneous Control
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc RS690M [Radeon X1200 Series]
02:04.0 CardBus bridge: Ricoh Co Ltd RL5c476 II (rev b6)
02:04.1 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Ricoh Co Ltd R5C832 IEEE 1394 Controller (rev 02)
10:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM5787M Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express (rev 02)
```

`lsusb`:

```
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 08ff:2580 AuthenTec, Inc. AES2501 Fingerprint Sensor
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 066f:8000 SigmaTel, Inc. MSCN MP3 Player
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 03f0:171d Hewlett-Packard Wireless (Bluetooth + WLAN) Interface [Integrated Module]
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`sudo lshw -class network`:

```
 *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetLink BCM5787M Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:10:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 02
       serial: 00:1a:4b:82:59:ee
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.116 firmware=sb v2.09 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:43 memory:d0000000-d000ffff
```

/etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

`sudo rfkill list`:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
      Soft blocked: no
      Hard blocked: no
1: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
      Soft blocked: yes
      Hard blocked: no
2: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
      Soft blocked: no
      Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: also have a look at `/etc/network/interfaces` and post contents of that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The output to `sudo rfkill list` shows that your network card is "soft-blocked".

This could happen when the wireless card has been signalled to switch-off - this is probably because of a Fn+ type switch.

If you don't identify the keyboard switch then perform the following steps:

1. run in a terminal:

   `sudo rfkill unblock hp-wifi; sudo rfkill unblock wifi; sudo rfkill unblock all`
2. rerun `sudo rfkill list` to confirm that the card has been unblocked.
3. reboot
4. rerun `sudo rfkill list` again to confirm unblocking as been retained.
5. rerun `sudo lshw -class network` - you should now see that the kernel has recognised (or not) the wireless card.

If the wireless kernel module has been recognised (it should not say "unclaimed"), Network Manager should now be able to see wireless networks that are available in your vacinity.

Comment: now they have all been unblocked. still no wireless connection.

Comment: ok - reboot - rerun `sudo rfkill list` to confirm unblocking as been retained.  Then rerun `sudo lshw -class network` - you should now see that the kernel has recognised (or not) the wireless card.  Add the output into your question.

Comment: It works! Cheers!

Comment: Do you have any idea how i can do the same with my Kubuntu 8.04? rfkill list doesn't work with it.

Comment: A very similiar topic: http://askubuntu.com/questions/59758/wireless-driver-not-detected-kubuntu-8-04

Comment: It worked with me. Other suggestions here did not