# Why is my wireless driver not detected?

Tags: wireless, kubuntu, 8.04

When typing `iwconfig` I only get "no wireless extensions"

How do I get the Ubuntu wireless driver to be detected?

```
lspci:
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile PM965/GM965/GL960 Memory Controller Hub (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 03)
00:1a.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 03)
00:1a.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 03)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 2 (rev 03)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 3 (rev 03)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 4 (rev 03)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1d.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1d.2 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 03)
00:1d.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev f3)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801HEM (ICH8M) LPC Interface Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801HBM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) IDE Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801HBM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) SATA AHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 03)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM5906M Fast Ethernet PCI Express (rev 02)
06:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR242x 802.11abg Wireless PCI Express Adapter (rev 01)

lsusb:
Bus 007 Device 003: ID 090c:1000 Feiya Technology Corp. Memory Bar
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 064e:a101 Suyin Corp. 
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 0000:0000  
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 0000:0000  
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 0000:0000  
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 0000:0000  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 0000:0000  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 0000:0000  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 0000:0000  


sudo lshw -class network:
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetLink BCM5906M Fast Ethernet PCI Express
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 02
       serial: 00:1b:38:df:ce:e9
       capacity: 100MB/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.86 latency=0 link=no module=tg3 multicast=yes port=twisted pair
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: AR242x 802.11abg Wireless PCI Express Adapter
       vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0



/etc/network/interfaces:
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
address 127.0.0.1
netmask 255.0.0.0
```

And `sudo rfkill list` doesn't work.

If I had any rep I would offer a bounty.

Comment: The newer versions are slow as a snail. i never really got what they ment by "supported", guess that means "kindly allows you to use".

Comment: ive installed lubuntu on my old laptop and it looks great. thanks for the advice.

Comment: I've completed the answer based on our discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure you already know that 8.04 is no longer supported for the Desktop- at a minimum I would try 10.04. It will make it easier to diagnose if you try this version.

If you are choosing to use 8.04 because the latest software has too higher demands for your hardware I would strongly recommend downloading Lubuntu 11.04.  Its a great lightweight distro.

I'll complete the answer by posting advice on how to compile up the driver from source.

Preparing your system:

```
sudo aptitude install build-essential
```

This will install all the required compilers.

Now you need to download the latest wireless drivers from here using the following command

```
wget http://wireless.kernel.org/download/compat-wireless-2.6/compat-wireless-2.6.tar.bz2
```

Now you have compat-wireless-2.6.tar.bz2 file you need to extract this file using the following command from the terminal

```
sudo tar -jxvf compat-wireless-2.6.tar.bz2
```

Move to the directory you extracted in terminal

```
cd directoryname
```

Run the following commands

```
make
sudo make install
sudo make unload
sudo make load
```

[source](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-get-atheros-ar5007eg-or-ar242x-wireless-cards-may-be-other-models-working-in-ubuntu-810-intrepid-ibex.html)