# Just installed Ubuntu, but my wireless networks aren't showing up

Tags: wireless, helpfile

As the title says, my wireless networks aren't showing up can someone help please? I have 12.04

Thanks.

Comment: Please check [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers).

Answer (score 1):

Since your question is not too descriptive, i would suggest a simple solution.

Connect to an ethernet cable. Goto Software Center and download "Additional Drivers" software. Run it, and then see if it finds any wireless drivers available on your machine, select it, install it and reboot. Check to see if it works.

Regards, WinuxUser

Comment: Thanks, I don't have any ethernet outlets in the room where my desktop is in, infact my whole house uses wireless connection, how do you suggest I try to connect? Sorry for the obvious questions, I'm pretty new inexperienced when it comes to computers.

Comment: Wireless drivers are not easy going when it comes to Ubuntu.If your hard switch cannot turn your wireless driver on and off,you must get to a wired connection to enable your wireless driver in Ubuntu first.

Comment: You can visit the following link and go thoroughly through each step suggested: http://askubuntu.com/questions/58881/wireless-driver-not-detected

Comment: @rickyshucks I used to have the same situation at my old house.  The only thing to do is buy an exceedingly long Ethernet cable (they aren't that expensive) and connect that way, until you can install the necessary drivers.  Borrow Internet from a neighbor if necessary :).